# Python Iterating in a dictionary to get empty key's

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello guys I'm trying to iterate from a dictionary to get the keys in case some of keys would be empty, but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Any idea ?

```
def val(**args):
    args = args
    print args



    # print args
    # print (args.keys())

val(name = '', country = 'Canada', phone = '')
```

Whit this example I got {'country': 'Canada', 'name': '', 'phone': ''} but when I'm really looking is to get only the keys of the empty keys in a list using append, the problem is that it gives me all the keys when and not just the empty keys.

In that case I would like to return something like this:
name, phone

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, why do you think that `args = args` does anything at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate the dictionary and extract keys where the value is an empty string:

```
empty_keys = [k for k, v in args.items() if v == '']
```

or as a function:

```
>>> def val(**args):
...     return [k for k, v in args.items() if v == '']
...
>>> val(name = '', country = 'Canada', phone = '')
['phone', 'name']
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how you get a list of the empty keys:

```
empty = [k for k, v in args.items() if not v or v.isspace()]
```

Notice that the above includes the cases when the value is `None` or `''` or only spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The for statement can be used to iterate over the key/values of a dictionary, then you can do what you want with them.

```
def val(args) :
   outputList = []
   for k, v in args :
      if v == '' :
         outputList.append(k)
   return outputList
```

This function will return a list made up of the keys whose value are the empty string.